# Give this child the height of dynamic parent in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I've found this question in multiple other threads on Stackoverflow although none of them did it for me.

I'm looking for a way to insert a vertical rule in every `aside` element inside my `article`. The `aside` however is dynamically filled. Some `aside`s inside `articles` are empty. I have multiple `articles`.

```
<article class="clearfix">  
    <img src="photo.jpg" alt="PNA group diensten">
    <p>paragraph</p>

    <aside>

    <span class="vr"></span>

       <div>Stuff with height, or no stuff</div>

    </aside>
</article>
```

This code kinda works:

```
$(".page-template-page-colSide main article aside span.vr").height( $(".page-template-page-colSide main article aside").height()).show();
```

The thing however, is that all the `span.vr` are now the same height. They get the height of the first `aside`.

How to set the height of the `span.vr` dynamically so it matches the specific `aside`?

Comment: Add your HTML in the question, better yet, make a JSfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(".page-template-page-colSide main article aside span.vr").each(function(){
    $(this).height( $(this).closest("aside").height() ).show();
});
```